# Vim keymappings with repeat keys

Tags: key-bindings

I have been a QtCreator user for long now. Just switching to JS & Go.

With FZF, I have created these mappings

```
nnoremap <C-k>  :Files! <CR>     
nnoremap <C-k>. :BTags! <CR>
```

So `<C-k>` is prefix for all my commands. I find this to be working, but I find my first key mapping is now delayed. I am assuming it's because vim has to wait for next key.

Wondering if there is a way to configure this delay.

Comment: The first mapping **is** CTRL+K, so Vim **must** wait to distinguish it from the second one.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2):

You can set [`'timeoutlen'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27timeoutlen%27) to control the length of this timeout. It defaults to 1000 ms, or one second.

This assumes that `'timeout'` is set, which is the default. If it isn't, then Vim will keep waiting for more keys when you have a prefix of a mapping pending.

My advice is to avoid the issue altogether, don't create mappings that are a prefix to other mappings. Instead, make sure they differ on the last character, to ensure each mapping will always be unambiguous and you won't depend on a timeout to trigger them.